# Is there a better way to programmatically insert content into a page?

Tags: pages, wp-insert-post, post-content

During activation of the plugin I'm writing, I insert a custom page. I can add `post_content` using the [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) command, which seems like a reasonable way to add a limited amount of content.

For example, something simple as part of an `array` could be:

`'post_content'='<h1> Header </h1>'`

However, I would like to add a full page of code. Is there a way, such as perhaps linking to a separate file, to insert significant amounts of content? I've tried `'post_content' => '<link rel="import" href="./test.html">'` but that doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone found a way to do this other than putting all the code directly into the array?

Comment: You could use `file_get_contents()` on a file in your plugin to get the contents into a variable and use that as the contents. Or you could create a shortcode for this content and make that the content.

Comment: A variable can hold “significant amounts of content” - maybe best show what test.html contains for better context.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that approach. @DavidSword I haven't developed "test.html" fully yet, but I suspect it would fit within a variable.

Comment: @JacobPeattie `file_get_contents()` works quite nicely, thank you. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Cheers!